# MySQL Benchmark

Tags: php, mysql, benchmarking, mysql-error-1242

I am trying to use MySQL benchmark to test some queries. But, I am running to an error.

```
SELECT benchmark (10000, (select title from user));
```

and in return I get this error;

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Does anyone know how to benchmark a query?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select title from user
```

This returns multiple rows, which won't work.

Refer to this link:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_benchmark

The expression you pass must return a scalar result.

You need to change the query such that it returns a single row:
ex:

```
select title from user where user_name = 'some_user'
```

Answer (score 11):

you can use the mysqlslap utility to benchmark queries, see: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlslap.html

Answer (score -1):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_benchmark

> Only scalar expressions can be used.
>   Although the expression can be a
>   subquery, it must return a single
>   column and at most a single row. For
>   example, BENCHMARK(10, (SELECT * FROM
>   t)) will fail if the table t has more
>   than one column or more than one row.

Try

```
SELECT BENCHMARK(10000, (SELECT title FROM user LIMIT 1));
```

Comment: Note: While that does fix the error, it's not actually going to help him benchmark the query he wants to test.