# Any known issue with INSERT INTO .. SELECT within a MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert

I am trying to call a INSERT INTO ... SELECT statement from a MySQL stored procedure.

I always end up having this error from MySQL : `ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row`

My **SELECT** statement surely return more than one rows but the **INSERT** statement on top of it don't.

What am I missing ?

Code :

```
PREPARE query FROM 'INSERT INTO tmpTable (client_program, ref_client, ref_household) SELECT ref_client_program, ref_member, \"84k3\" FROM client_program_members WHERE ref_client_program IN (74)';
EXECUTE query ;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;
```

Comment: [Reference][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971150/mysql-benchmark

Comment: @Mithun: [Comment formatting FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but try this line -

```
PREPARE query FROM 'INSERT INTO `tmpTable`(client_program, ref_client, ref_household) SELECT ref_client_program, ref_member, ''84k3'' FROM client_program_members WHERE ref_client_program IN(74)';
```

Answer (score -1):

It is indeed possile to do an `insert ... select`.
And you can have multiple rows from that select.

The following code should work.

```
DECLARE sql varchar(1000);
SET sql = CONCAT("INSERT INTO tmpTable (client_program, ref_client, ref_household) "
               , " SELECT ref_client_program, ref_member, \'84k3\' "
               , " FROM client_program_members WHERE ref_client_program = ? ");

PREPARE query FROM sql;
SET @client_prog = 74; 
EXECUTE query USING @client_prog;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;
```