# MySQL Benchmark Error : 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I read this topic [MySQL Benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971150/mysql-benchmark/1971162#1971162) 
My problem :

```
mysql> SELECT benchmark(10000,(SELECT id FROM zd )  );
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

mysql> SELECT benchmark(10000,(SELECT * FROM zd LIMIT 1 )  );
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

If I want to measure the time sampling full table?

```
  mysql> SELECT benchmark(10000,(SELECT * FROM zd  )  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should limit your record count to 1 as below.

```
SELECT benchmark(10000,(SELECT id FROM zd limit 1)  );
```

Benchmark is the function which is going to execute your select statement 10K times. So you cant do full table select with benchmark. See MySQL [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_benchmark) for details